# http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main 404 not found

Tags: apt

I try to install openjdk-8-jre but it cannot find all necessary packages. What can I do?

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  openjdk-8-jre-headless
Suggested packages:
  icedtea-8-plugin openjdk-8-jre-jamvm libnss-mdns fonts-ipafont-gothic
  fonts-ipafont-mincho ttf-wqy-microhei | ttf-wqy-zenhei fonts-indic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 27,0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 99,7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u131-b11-0ubuntu1.16.04.2
  404  Not Found
...
```

There are some more links that are not found but I can't post them because I'm a new user

Comment: If you format the output correctly as code (with the `{}` button) it will not count as a link. Check your internet connection/try using a different mirror. The problem has nothing to do with openjdk - APT is apparently failing to connect to the main repositories

Comment: I have also been getting this error since yesterday so I think it has something to do with the mirror.